# Laravel 4 authentication login issue

Tags: redirect, authentication, laravel

In my Laravel login route, I have the following code:

```
Route::get('/login', function() {
    $credentials = Input::only('username', 'password');
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return Redirect::intended('/');
    }
    return Redirect::to('login');
});
```

When I try to just access `/login`, I get a "web page has a redirect loop" error. How do I fix this?

TIA - Joe

Comment: Post your routes for `login` form and `login` processing method.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your logic, if a user has invalid credentials then they will be redirected to /login which will try to validate their credentials again causing an infinite loop. You should split your /login into a post and a get route to prevent this. In your view when you submit the login form, it should be sent with POST.

```
Route::get('/login', function() {
   //do nothing here, just return the view for the login form
});

Route::post('/login', function() {
    $credentials = Input::only('username', 'password');
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return Redirect::intended('/');
    }
    return Redirect::to('login');
});
```